# C++: how is construction by initialization list done?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, language-lawyer, list-initialization

C++ allows instantiating a class, setting the public members' value via an initialization list, as the example below shows for `b1`:

```
class B {
public:
    int i;
    std::string str;
}; 

B b1{ 42,"foo" };
B b2();
```

; however, if I provide a constructor

```
B(int k)    {   }
```

, it won't compile.

So, what's going on behind the hood? 
Is it that when no constructor is provide, the compiler will provide one? But how could it provide one with initialization list? I thought it will just provide a "blank" constructor taking no input, as the example shows for `b2`. Or does it provide both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But how could it provide one with initialization list?

No, it won't.

Note that for [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation) `B b1{ 42,"foo" };`, [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) is performed.

> If `T` is an aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed.

And `B` **is** an [aggregate type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Explanation),

> An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> ```
> array type
> class type (typically, struct or union), that has 
>
>     no private or protected non-static data members
>     no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed)
>     no virtual, private, or protected base classes
>     no virtual member functions
> ```

That's why `B b1{ 42,"foo" };` works well.

And If you provide a user-defined constructor, `B` becomes non-aggregate type, then aggregate initialization won't work again. In this case, you can only initialize `B` like `B b1{42};` or `B b2(42);`, which will call the appropriate constructor.

BTW: After providing a user-defined constructor (taking one parameter), the [implicitly-declared default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-declared_default_constructor) won't be declared by the compiler again. It means `B b2;` or `B b2{};` won't work again.

BTW2: `B b2();` might be a function declaration. See [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).